# What is an efficient way in terms of memory to store audio files and images in an android app?

Tags: android

I am going to build an app which has to play 300-400 songs and 1000-2000 images. What is most suitable way to implement this one. For my requirement I've two concerns

1. Storing all files into 'Resources' folder in app
2. Storing and retrieving from database using BLOB

But I think both the above procedures may take more memory.

Please suggest any other way to implement this one.

Comment: They both use the same amount of "memory" on the device as it's binary data. A filesystem or database solution is where you want to concentrate. A filesystem based solution is more efficient because you simply point your app to where the file is; but what happens if the file doesn't get copied during the install process? More complicated and system resource heavy is using a BLOB in a DB. Less efficient but a tiny bit easier to check for errors when copying the DB file between devices. A DB also allows you to offer a slight bit more protection of preventing people copying individual files.

Comment: So should I use DB or Files?

Comment: It's for you to decide... You should know how you want to store the data for easier programming or more secure data...

Comment: Although but which one is the most suitable way in terms of memory. Security not matters for my app Or do we have any other way like using local server ? I am new to android development can you please clarify me on this more..thank you..

Comment: If I were developing I'd have my resources stored in a folder and my app would refer to them. The resource locations could be kept in a file or a DB...